# Creating New Branch in Katalon studio GitHub Integrtion

Tags: git, github, katalon-studio

I'm using a Katalon studio for Automation testing, we have to create a separate branch in GitHub to track all the changes.

I'm cloning the repository into my Katalon Studio and try to create a New Branch for adding new stuff. While creating a branch it is asking for a source branch?

Let me know which source I can choose? (local master / Remote master)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This question is really a [git](/questions/tagged/git) question, more than a Katalon related question.

In git, you create branches in your local repository. Katalon assumes that you'd like to share your local content with somebody else via a remote repository.

The branch that you created locally is not present in the remote repository.

In the most basic scenario, you want to create a branch with the same name in your remote ([github](/questions/tagged/github) server) and track your local branch in the newly created remote branch.

I hope this can put you in the right direction.